# Puppet package installation on Linux/CentOS

Tags: yum, puppet, package-management, packages

I am new to Puppet - I have been playing around learning the basics. Most of the examples ( except the very basic ones )  that are on the [puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/) page do not work for me - either some dependency is missing or package is not found. I do not see the logs explaining what went wrong ( even if I run the `--test` or `--verbose` option)

1. Can anyone clarify how does puppet manage to install any given package from a title ( for example  starting from a manifest as below :

   ```
   class httpd {
         package { 'httpd':
              ensure => installed,
         }
   }
   ```

   Here - starting from 'httpd' - what happens when we run 
   puppet apply on this manifest ? Where does it find the installer ( ie where is the repository - where is it configured ? )
2. Specifically , I am getting this error :

   ```
   err: /Stage[main]/Ntp/Package[httpd]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install httpd' returned 1: Error: failure: repodata/filelists.xml.gz from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
   You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                          package-cleanup --dupes
                          rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
   ```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

It is trying to run yum to install httpd

```
 /usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install httpd
```

Try running that as root but I'm sure it will fail so try

```
 /usr/bin/yum clean all
 /usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install httpd
```

If that doesn't work your yum repositories are not working so you'll have to fix that file. Probably files in

```
/etc/yum.repos.d
```

Answer (score 1):

While Mike's answer solves problem definitely - I would do similar thing through Puppet.

For example as a first step I would add following piece of code before installing any package

```
exec {'yum-clean-all':
  command =>  'yum clean all',
  path    =>  '/usr/bin',
  user    =>  'root',
  before  =>  Package[httpd],
}
```

Similarly any execution that needs to be done before installing packages should be executed through puppet as a first step.